# Custom skin Button in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, button, skinning, skin

Morning all

I don't know why this isn't simpler to achieve! Here we go:

In my pure Flash CS5 AS3 project, I need to make some Buttons. Many different sorts of Buttons, which have different sets of skins. Completely different.

So, taking the Button component and changing the skins in the Symbol is not good enough, because that changes *all* Buttons. And I need lots of different ones.

We all know how to re-skin the core Button component, which has the effect of altering all buttons.

Does anyone know how to make discrete customisations of Button, or something to similar effect?

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean.. If you need to have multiple different buttons why can't you just create multiple buttons using the Convert to symbol feature from the context menu when selecting objects in the UI?

If you need to maintain some type of functionality across these buttons, then I can recommend encapsulating all of this into a class that has a property `skin:SimpleButton`. What you can do here is have a setter for skin that applies your event listeners or whatever like this:

```
public function set skin(btn:SimpleButton):void
{
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _someFunc);
}
```

All you'll really need to do then is either create some classes for each of your different buttons that specify the skin to use in the constructor:

```
public function SomeButton()
{
    skin = new MyLibraryButton();
}
```

Or do it on the fly:

```
var button:MyButton = new MyButton();
button.skin = new MyLibraryButton();
```

Is this what you were after?

---

Here is a more complete example of what I am describing above:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class MyButton extends Object
    {
        // Properties
        private var _skin:SimpleButton;

        /**
         * Defines the button skin to use
         * @param btn Reference to an instance of SimpleButton
         */
        public function set skin(btn:SimpleButton):void
        {
            _skin = btn;

            btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
        }

        /**
         * Called when the skin (button) has been clicked
         * @param e MouseEvent.CLICK
         */
        private function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("Button was clicked");
        }

        /**
         * Getters
         */
        public function get skin():SimpleButton{ return _skin; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marty

Okay what I mean is that I need the full functionality of the flash Button component. That is, multiple skins for the different states, including the toggling, selected, disabled etc.

So just hooking a graphic with a click handler won't really cut it.

An example is that i'm using a client's set of button state graphics, and doing a re-skin job on Button.

Comment: Yep so that stuff is easy to achieve/inbuilt if you create a button by selecting some graphics, right clicking and then selecting Convert to symbol. From here select button and click OK. Once you've done this you'll be able to double-click your new button to be presented with a set of 4 frames labelled in a way that will clearly represent each of those states. All you need to do from here is create some graphics for each of the new frames to represent their corresponding state. Hope this helps.

Comment: Damn, that was easy! Done it, thanks!
Always wondered what selecting Button did when creating a Symbol ...

Okay, taking this a step further. How could I reproduce all the functionality that the Button componenet has, i.e. the 4 selected states, disabled, etc?

Comment: So in response to my original post about re-skinning Button, what I need longterm is to have a custom symbol/component, backed by either fl.controls.Button or a subclass of that, and be able to put in completely different graphics.

I started a subclass of Button, with a set of function get/set to change the upSkin and friends style values, so that it could use whatever graphics I wanted. But problems started ...